# Vue cast event type syntax error with bracket notation

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I would like to type a `ChangeEvent` in Vue using the Typescript bracket notation for casting because it's clearer for me.
However, I get a linter error when casting `event.target` with bracket notation, and not with the `as` syntax. Is there a way to get rid of this error?

```
const updateRadio = (event: Event) => {
  emit('change', (event.target as HTMLInputElement).checked); // No error
  emit('change', (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).checked); // Error
};
```

I get this error from ESLint

```sh
Parsing error: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?eslint
```

Comment: It's not just a matter of taste but that bracket syntax is in conflict with JSX, which is everywhere, including Vue. I'm quite sure the error is that because JSX is enabled. I'm not sure which part of a setup is responsible for this because it's not straightforward at all for Vue SFC. .vue files certainly get a different treatment rather than .ts/tsx. Not using obsolete syntax will save you the trouble. Any way, this is very specific to your setup. If you're interested in fixing it, consider providing it. If it's Vue CLI, its version and all config modifications could be listed

Comment: Does the Vue documentation mention that bracket notation in .vue files for Typescript casting is obsolete? The project has been bootstraped using NuxtJS

Comment: No, this is common TS knowledge. In vanilla TS setup this is regulated by the choice of .ts/tsx extension but this differs between TS loaders, and .vue loader does some magic under the hood too. It could be expected that it's affected with `<script lang="ts">`  and `<script lang="tsx">` but it's likely not the case, not to mention that the way IDEs handle it may differ from compiler behaviour, so the risk is doubled. I prefer bracket syntax either but ditched it because it needs to be written differently in JSX files any way.